Error Loading bindy.dll When Using libximc for Rotary Table Control
I'm trying to control a physical rotary table using a proprietary controller, which utilizes the custom library libximc for communication. I've installed the library via pip as per the manufacturer's instructions. More details on using the device and the library can be found here (https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1xJawpc-0CIZLDlwkefzSgWrAyBVSlaMl#scrollTo=8a959c87).
After running the provided test code, I encounter the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\aidas\Desktop\DAQMIK\VirtualRotaryTable\VirtualMotorControl.py", line 4, in <module>
    import libximc.highlevel as ximc
  File "C:\Users\aidas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\libximc\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from libximc.lowlevel import *  # noqa: It's very difficult to trace which objects from old lowlevel binding are needed
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\aidas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\libximc\lowlevel\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>  
    from libximc.lowlevel._lowlevel import *  # noqa: It's very difficult to trace which objects from old lowlevel binding are needed
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\aidas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\libximc\lowlevel\_lowlevel.py", line 86, in <module>
    lib = ximc_shared_lib()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\aidas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\libximc\lowlevel\_lowlevel.py", line 84, in ximc_shared_lib
    return _load_lib()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\aidas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\libximc\lowlevel\_lowlevel.py", line 79, in _load_lib
    raise RuntimeError(error_msg)
RuntimeError: Unable to load library. Paths tried:
Error loading file C:\Users\aidas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\libximc\lowlevel\..\library-files\win64\bindy.dll - Could not find module 'C:\Users\aidas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\libximc\lowlevel\..\library-files\win64\bindy.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
Error loading file ..\..\..\..\..\win64\bindy.dll - Could not find module '..\..\..\..\..\win64\bindy.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.

My code (provided by manufacturer):
import pathlib
import os
import time
import libximc.highlevel as ximc

virtual_device_filename = "virtual_motor_controller_1.bin"
virtual_device_file_path = os.path.join(
    pathlib.Path().cwd(),
    virtual_device_filename
)
# Devices search
devices = ximc.enumerate_devices(
    ximc.EnumerateFlags.ENUMERATE_NETWORK |
    ximc.EnumerateFlags.ENUMERATE_PROBE
)

if len(devices) == 0:
    print("The real devices were not found. A virtual device will be used.")
else:
    # Print real devices list
    print("Found {} real device(s):".format(len(devices)))
    for device in devices:
        print("  {}".format(device)) 

What could be the cause of the problem and how to fix it?
Identical Setup Works on Desktop:
I've followed the exact same steps on my desktop, where the code works without any issues.
Pointing to the DLL Path Directly:
I tried modifying the PATH environment variable in the script to point directly to the full path of the bindy.dll file:
import ctypes
import os
import libximc.highlevel as ximc

dll_path = r"C:\Users\aidas\Downloads\libximc-20241009T030645Z-001.zip\libximc\library-files\win64\bindy.dll" 
os.environ['PATH'] = dll_path + ";" + os.environ['PATH']

virtual_device_filename = "virtual_motor_controller_1.bin"
virtual_device_file_path = os.path.join(pathlib.Path().cwd(), virtual_device_filename)

devices = ximc.enumerate_devices(ximc.EnumerateFlags.ENUMERATE_NETWORK | ximc.EnumerateFlags.ENUMERATE_PROBE)

if len(devices) == 0:
    print("The real devices were not found. A virtual device will be used.")
else:
    print("Found {} real device(s):".format(len(devices)))
    for device in devices:
        print("  {}".format(device))


Environment Information:
OS: Windows 10 (64-bit)
Python Version: 3.9 (64-bit)
Library Version: libximc 2.13.3 (installed via pip)
Laptop: Asus Aspire E15 (Intel Core i5-8215U, 8GB RAM)
Desktop: Custom-built PC (Intel Core i5, 32GB RAM)
